# NoSuchMethodError when using @Step annotation in Allure2

Tags: java, groovy, allure

I'm trying to implement Allure2 as a reporting tool for our automation suite but I seem to be running into an issue with the `@Step` annotation.

I have the imports in place, the IDE recognizes it perfectly, I can see the package under dependencies and the specific class is available to browse and everything seems to be correct but when I try to run the test I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.qameta.allure.aspects.StepsAspects.aspectOf()Lio/qameta/allure/aspects/StepsAspects;
```

If I remove the `@Step` annotation everything works perfectly, including the report.

Googling around all I could find was that this very same issue seemed to have been solved during beta and I'm using the latest version as of today. I also have this implemented on another project and it works great with the same versions but even after scouring through both `pom.xml` files I can't figure out where I might be screwing up.

Here are the relevant bits of my pom settings.

```
<properties>
    <!--DEPENDENCIES VERSIONS-->
    <allure2.version>2.6.0</allure2.version>
    <allure.maven.version>2.9</allure.maven.version>
    <maven.surefire.plugin.version>2.19.1</maven.surefire.plugin.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.9.1</aspectj.version>
</properties>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
        <version>${allure2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
        <version>${allure.maven.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.surefire.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <allure.directory>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</allure.directory>
                    <allure.results.directory>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</allure.results.directory>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng-run.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                </argLine>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
            <version>${allure.maven.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <properties>
                    <allure.issues.tracker.pattern>######################</allure.issues.tracker.pattern>
                    <allure.tests.management.pattern>#######################</allure.tests.management.pattern>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I don't think specifying the `allure-maven` dependency in both places is necessary. Just to rule it out I've tried with it only in the plugin section and same issue.

Any thoughts?.

Comment: Today, I get the same Error, and it begins since allure-java-commons was changed to <version>2.15.0</version> When I set version to: <version>2.14.0</version>
everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using custom `aop.xml` configuration file thats excludes Allure aspects from weaving. Make sure that package `io.qameta.allure` is included in weaver configuration

Comment: Looks like that was exactly the problem. I'm upgrading the allure installation in this project as opposed to starting one from scratch like I did on the other one and I had no idea it had a custom `aop.xml`. It was including the old packages for an old Allure version.

Comment: This solved the same problem for me - in my specific case I needed to remove the old include (`<include within="ru.yandex.qatools.allure.*"/>`) and replace it with `<include within="io.qameta.allure..*"/>`.